# where to process mysql queries in codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Where should we process mysql queries in CodeIgniter application?
For example in a simple project we do like this :

for controller:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
    function posts(){
        $data['query'] = $this->blog_model->index_posts();
        $this->load->view('blog_view', $data);
    }
}
```

and in view :

```
<?php
while ($post = mysql_fetch_object($query)):
?>
<div>
    <p><?= $post->body; ?></p>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But, if we want to do something with body of post before print  where should it be done?
For example, I want to write a function that formats the body of post and pass the body to it before doing echo.

Where should it be placed according to CoeIgniter's structure and recommended practices? (best option)

- in the controller? (if so , how to use it)
- in the view?
- write a helper?
- other approaches ?

Comment: The **Model** represents your data structures. Typically your model classes will contain functions that help you retrieve, insert, and update information in your database. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: If you are using CodeIgnoter, you are already doing it wrong. **CodeIgniter is not MVC framework**. It does not implement even anything resembling MVC.

Comment: what do you mean Codeigniter is not MVC framework ?? would you please explain more about that ?

Comment: It is not implementing MVC. There is no view, just a template, which is called "view". And there is no model layer, only group of data access classes, which you call "models". And then you take all the business logic which had no place on "models" and all the presentation logic , put it all in single class and call it "controller". That is not MVC pattern. It is just making sh*t up and calling it "mvc", for marketing purposes.

Comment: "no model layer" do you refer to lack of no ORM ?? well which php framework implements real MVC and is lightweight too? interested to know your opinion.

Comment: None of the popular ones. Most of PHP frameworks just mimic Rails. And model layer has nothing to do with ORM. Maybe [this] helps a bit. And what gave you an impression that MVC patterns is made for "lightweight solutions" ?

Comment: i didn't say MVC pattern is for lightweight solution. i want a popular (for good support) php framework which implements MVC(for reasons like maintenance) and also is lightweight (so doesn't load unnecessary code and has higher performance)

Comment: None of PHP frameworks loads unnecessary files. That's why PHP has `spl_autoload_register()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse that function create a helper. If you want this function only once put it in your controller and call from that controller.

Models are just for accessing database or maybe in few other cases, but mostly just for accessing things in database or editing, deleting etc. and sending the result to controller for further processing.

In your case I would stick with helper.

E.g. you will create a file **top_mega_best_functions.php** and put it inside helpers folder.

Than you write ther e.g. something like

```
function red_text($input) {

    echo '<span style="color: red;">';
    echo $input;
    echo '</span>';
}
```

Then load the helper in your autoloader file or load before using.

And use in your view or controller like

```
$blablabla = "This text will be red";

red_text($blablabla);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what is recommended:

**Controller:**

```
function posts() {
   $this->load->model("blog_model");
   $data['rows'] = $this->blog_model->index_posts(); 
   $this->load->view("blog_view", $data);
}
```

**Model: (blog_model.php)**

```
function index_posts() {
   $this->load->database();
   $query = $this->db->get('your_table');
   $return = array();
   foreach ($query->result_array() as $line) {
      $line['body'] = ... do something with the body....
      $return[] = $line;
   }
   return $return;
}
```

**View: (blog_view.php)**

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $line): ?>
<div>
<p><?php echo $line['column']; ?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Basically what happens is your model returns a multidimensional array that is passed the view and processed using a `foreach()` loop.

Good luck!

Comment: i think you didn't get my question. i said i want to write a function that formats data retrieved from mysql before doing echo. i asked where to write this function and how to use it ?

Comment: If you're talking about how to display it, put it in the view. If you're talking about logic on the data, you could either put it in the model or the view. Take a look at my edit

Comment: Take a look at what I changed in the Model. I added another `foreach()` that steps through each post (I assume that's what you're dealing with) and changes something about the body, adds it to a new array, and returns that new array for `echo`ing in the view.

Comment: well it works. but i think this way isn't good in performance( the second foreach() is unnecessary). i think a better idea is to write a function that formats the content and pass the content through this function in _view_ . but my question is how to write function that be available in _view_ and **how to call** it in _view_ ??

Comment: You should not call a function in your view that communicates with the controller, all data that the view should use needs to be available before it loads. Helper functions is fine in the view, put them at the top.